# how to plot a data dot plot based on y axis on top of one another

Tags: r, ggplot2

My data looks like this

```
df<- structure(list(Data = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 
9L, 10L, 11L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 
23L, 8L, 12L), .Label = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", 
"GH", "H", "I", "J", "JJ", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", 
"S", "T", "U", "V"), class = "factor"), Case1 = c(0.775230796, 
0.752114939, 0.738305175, 0.579739531, 0.573781392, 0.572924713, 
0.563521221, 0.558172423, 0.557918102, 0.552505171, 0.551921725, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Case2 = c(NA, 
NA, 0.729029032, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.736282677, 0.702296369, 
NA, 0.736060259, 0.735161607, 0.735100052, 0.734870114, 0.732743364, 
0.703591649, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Case3 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.735568109, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Case4 = c(0.713963088, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.781378904, 
0.769328289, NA, NA, NA), Case5 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.693759347, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.688396329, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, 0.6781535, NA, NA), Case6 = c(0.795781477, 0.793446723, 
0.814514206, NA, 0.773564937, NA, NA, 0.783075476, NA, NA, NA, 
0.742827684, 0.796443568, NA, 0.75610514, 0.751162004, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, 0.738104459, NA), Case7 = c(0.732114731, 0.720226731, 
0.782045984, NA, 0.717304483, NA, NA, 0.674992626, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, 0.71098987, NA, 0.676952218, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
0.676754903)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -23L))
```

I am trying to remove the rows that have only 1 value or completely NA
so to remove those with complete NA I can do the following

```
mydf<- df[!(rowSums(is.na(df))),]
```

I can plot it like this

```
library(reshape)
library(ggplot2)
mm <- melt(df, id='Data')
ggplot(data = mm, aes(x = Data, y = value, fill = variable)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity', position = 'dodge')
```

The issue is that this is bar plot, I want to have a dot plot for example for A in one line on top of each other and shows the label of case1, case 2, case 3 ,....

something like this

[image]

in the y axis, the "Data", in the x axis "values" and the labels as "variables" with different color an size

Comment: `mydf<- df[!(rowSums(is.na(df))),]` doing this will remove all rows...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
  gather(variable, value, -Data) %>%
  mutate(value = round(value*100)/100) %>%   # Aligns bins to 0.1
  ggplot(aes(x = value, fill = variable)) + 
  geom_dotplot(stackgroups = T)
```

[image]

Please note, a dot plot inherently rounds the data into bins (otherwise there will be no stacking unless values match exactly). With a minor adjustment, you can make ggplot pick the binning on its own (I think by default the bins reflect 1/30 of the range of the data). If you want to control the size of the bins, use `binwidth`.

I include `binpositions = "all"` here to make sure the Cases are put into the same bins as the other Cases, otherwise they will use their own bins that don't correspond to other Cases' bins, and they won't stack.

```
df %>% 
  gather(variable, value, -Data) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = value, fill = variable)) + 
  geom_dotplot(stackgroups = T, binpositions = "all")
```

[image]

Comment: I don't want to add or round values. if they are plot only with a dots small ones corresponding to their values, is already ok, Y axis does not show the Data!

Comment: A dot plot is typically (exclusively in my experience) used on binned data. Are you looking to make a scatter plot? You can certainly use the exact values for the x axis, but if they are all distinct values, how do you want them to "stack"?

Comment: Please clarify your question, since it seems to be asking for a dot plot (which is a form of histogram using binned data), but it also seems you don't want binning.